# How to change TextFiled widget background color when focus

Tags: flutter, textfield

I have a TextField widget which has default background color red. 
I want to change the background color to blue when the TextFiled is focused. But I can't do that.

There are three relative properties about the color I have tried.

```
filled: true,
fillColor: Colors.red,
focusColor: Colors.blue,
```

The result is only filled is set to true, the fillColor worked and the focusColor never work.
Can you tell me what to do?

Comment: If an answer helped you fix your issue, remember to mark it as correct so that other users can find it easily.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use a FocusNode on your TextField and a color variable to change the color:

**Declarations**

```
FocusNode _textFieldFocus = FocusNode();
Color _color = Colors.red;

@override
void initState() {
  _textFieldFocus.addListener((){
    if(_textFieldFocus.hasFocus){
      setState(() {
        _color = Colors.blue;
      });
    }else{
      setState(() {
        _color = Colors.red;
      });
    }
  });
  super.initState();
}
```

**Widget**

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    fillColor: _color,
    filled: true
  ),
  focusNode: _textFieldFocus,
),
```