# Change background color on TextField when focused

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-textformfield

I have a form with lots of input fields. I would like to change the background color when a TextField has focus:

[image]

[image]

This is my TextField:

```
TextFormField(
                focusNode: _textFieldFocus,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Input test',
                  filled: true,
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 3),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

I´ve searched some time for a solution, but it seems that you have to wrap the TextField in a stateful widget that uses a FocusNode. Seen in this post for an example:
[How to change TextFiled widget background color when focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59712673/how-to-change-textfiled-widget-background-color-when-focus)

I am not too keen on this solution, because I have a lot of text fields, and I think it is unnecessary to create stateful instances for each "dumb" text input I have. I would prefer if there was a focusBackgroundColor property or alike.
So is there an easier solution than wrapping a TextField in a stateful widget?

Comment: See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialStateProperty-class.html to be able to specify colors based on combinations of states.

Comment: Interesting approach, but that seems to only work with TextButtons and alike, not a TextField? I am getting an 'The argument type 'MaterialStateProperty<Color>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color?'' When I try to assign it as a fillColor to the Textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a listener on `FocusNode` to use `setState` for UI update. to change color we can use `fillColor: _textFieldFocus.hasFocus ? Colors.purple : null`, modify the color you want.

```dart
late final _textFieldFocus = FocusNode()
  ..addListener(() {
    setState(() {});
  });
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
        TextFormField(
          focusNode: _textFieldFocus,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            fillColor: _textFieldFocus.hasFocus ? Colors.purple : null,
            labelText: 'Input test',
            filled: true,
            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 3),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

With `ValueNotifier`

```dart
class TestA extends StatelessWidget {
  TestA({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final ValueNotifier<bool> _textFiledIsFocused = ValueNotifier(false);
  late final FocusNode _textFieldFocus = FocusNode()
    ..addListener(() {
      _textFiledIsFocused.value = _textFieldFocus.hasFocus;
    });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
            valueListenable: _textFiledIsFocused,
            builder: (context, value, child) => TextFormField(
              focusNode: _textFieldFocus,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                fillColor: value ? Colors.purple : null,
                labelText: 'Input test',
                filled: true,
                focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    width: 3,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that requires that the TextField is wrapped in a Stateful widget, and because of performance reasons (and to simplify things), I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Performance reasons?

Comment: Can you explain a little more, what do you mean by *performance reasons*. If you have a large snippet, you might create a separate context/widget for heavy widgets. Also the UI will rebuild only when focused is changed. If you like to have more specific check [ValueNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html).

Comment: I am new to flutter, and guess I am wrong on this one :) Lets say I have 100 form input fields. Isn´t 100 instances of a stateful widget more memory/cpu demanding than 100 Stateless widgets?

Comment: If you have 100 widgets, more likely you will use scrolling widget , in that case use `.builder` or sliver widget for performance.  As for the second approach you can use `StatelessWidget` with valueNotifier or other statemanagemnet like provider/riverpod/bloc. You can find more about [ui-performance](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/ui-performance#:~:text=Flutter%20aims%20to%20provide%2060,UI%20doesn't%20render%20smoothly.)

Comment: Looks like I have a lot of reading to do! But thanks for the info, and the Stateles widget approach with the ValueNotifier works 